# How do I properly do a dismax query using solrnet

Tags: solr, solrnet

I know I need to add the following code to change to dismax.

```
ExtraParams = new Dictionary<string, string> { {"qt", "dismax"} }
```

But how do I pass the "qf" values? I tried this with no avail:

```
new Dictionary<string, string> { {"qt", "dismax"},{"qf","field1 field2"} }
```

and

```
var matchingItems = solr.Query(new LocalParams {{"type", "dismax"},{"qf","field1 field2"}} 
+ BuildQuery(parameters) ...
```

Even passing only the ExtraParams I get a 404 bad request.

This is the logged queries

Local parameters + extraparams

```
GETting 'q={!type=dismax qf='field1 field2'}query text, start=0, rows=10,
spellcheck=true, facet=true, facet.field=especialidadefacet,
f.especialidadefacet.facet.mincount=1, facet.field=tipofacet,
f.tipofacet.facet.mincount=1, facet.field=estadofacet, f.estadofacet.facet.mincount=1,
qt=dismax' from '/select'
```

only extra params

```
GETting 'q=query text, start=0, rows=10, spellcheck=true, facet=true,
facet.field=especialidadefacet, f.especialidadefacet.facet.mincount=1,
facet.field=tipofacet, f.tipofacet.facet.mincount=1, facet.field=estadofacet,
f.estadofacet.facet.mincount=1, qt=dismax' from '/select'
```

Comment: The LocalParams one looks good to me. The output is just as described in the Solr wiki: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LocalParams . Are you sure you're not forgetting the core name or something?

Comment: wait, why are you using qt=dismax **and** localparams? do you have a "dismax" request handler registered in your config?

Comment: Nope, don't remenber setting up a request handler at the config.
Should I use only the local parameters, is that the intended behaviour withou a config for dismax as default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `qt` parameter selects a request handler. So if you don't have a request handler named 'dismax' and you define `qt=dismax` you'll get a 404.

So either define qt=dismax and a 'dismax' request handler, or alternatively, just use the dismax query parser via LocalParams.

Answer (score 1):

(Very late reply but worth for anyone landing here)

Try using local params, it would be something like:

```
solr.Query(new LocalParams {{"type", "dismax"},{"qf", "myfield"}} + new SolrQuery("solr rocks"));
```

Look at the LocalParams section in:
https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Querying.md