# Does SolrNet support query parser?

Tags: java, solr, solrnet

Does SolrNet support query parser? How to use it? I can't find any documentation about SolrNet query parsers

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can either use LocalParams or you [can use ExtraParams](https://github.com/SolrNet/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Querying.md) to make Solrnet switch the query parser in Solr:

> Solr has lots of features that aren't directly mapped in SolrNet, but you can enable and use most of them with the ExtraParams dictionary. Parameters defined in ExtraParams are directly passed to the Solr querystring. [..]
>
> Or enable DisMax instead of the standard request handler:

```
ISolrOperations<Product> solr = ...
var products =
    solr.Query(SolrQuery.All, new QueryOptions {
        ExtraParams = new Dictionary<string, string> {
            {"qt", "dismax"}
        }
    });
```

Or by using LocalParams as shown in the answers to [How do I properly do a dismax query using solrnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065357/how-do-i-properly-do-a-dismax-query-using-solrnet).